# Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, firewall, msdtc

I am running some jobs using Dotnet code. This job generally will do the series of CRUD operation using SQL database. It is working fine in Dev or QA servers but when I tried to debug in local for performance. I am getting below error and unable to find the cause.

> The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from
> the source transaction manager
> due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception
> for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support
> for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)

I tried hard to find the cause of it but I got one thing is that, Job is doing one connection first and if its trying to open any other connection for further insert/delete, its throwing this error. I am not sure how its working in server but not in local machine.

Any leads will be helpful.